# What is the reason for adding MediaElement to VisualTree?

Tags: wpf, mediaelement

I'm trying to find out why the last commented command is necessary in order to play a sound:

```
private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

  MediaElement MediaElement1 = new MediaElement();
  MediaElement1.Source = new Uri(@"My-absolute-path");
  //myGrid.Children.Add(MediaElement1);
}
```

Does anybody know?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to add it to the visual tree, you probably want to use [MediaPlayer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediaplayer(v=VS.85).aspx) instead of [MediaElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.mediaelement(v=VS.85).aspx).

```
private void Window_ContentRendered(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MediaPlayer MediaPlayer1 = new MediaPlayer();
    MediaPlayer1.Open(new Uri(@"My-absolute-path"));
    MediaPlayer1.Play();
}
```

See [Multimedia Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970915(VS.85).aspx):

> MediaElement is a UIElement that is
>   supported by The Layout System and can
>   be consumed as the content of many
>   controls. It is also usable in
>   Extensible Application Markup Language
>   (XAML) as well as code. MediaPlayer,
>   on the other hand, is designed for
>   Drawing objects and lacks layout
>   support. Media loaded using a
>   MediaPlayer can only be presented
>   using a VideoDrawing or by directly
>   interacting with a DrawingContext.
>   MediaPlayer cannot be used in XAML.